# Getting Facebook App Approval for Registration, Signing In and Sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-share, facebook-app-requests

1) Do we need to get Facebook app approval to implement registration and signing in via Facebook in the project? The website needs to fetch user data to fill in the registration form, and to sign in in the same way.

2) As another disirable feature on the website, we need to make and trace wall posts (i.e. make a wall post on the user's Facebook page, and get the post id). For this we definitely need app approval, right?

3) So here we get the main question: we need app approval, but what should we do to get it? Meaning, is it mandatory to record a screencast, and how can we record it without a working Facebook button?

4) Neither have I found any facebook developer support contacts to address, just a reference to this site. Any clues?

5) And the last question: how long does the review last? Is it even reasonable to make such a request if the project lifetime is just about a month or two?

Comment: Sorry, but to me this does not look like you did make an actual proper attempt to try and find the answers to these questions yourself upfront ... The documentation has a whole section that deals with App Review. _“and how can we record it without a working Facebook button?”_ - if you don’t have it working, then you have nothing to submit in the first place.

Comment: And as for 2), if you actually mean user timelines (and not pages the user might be an admin of), then you have also rather neglected to keep up with the current developments in that regard ... because posting to user timelines via API is not possible at all any more.